# How to get element order number

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i get order number of some element by javascript/jquery?

```
<ul>
 <li>Anton</li>
 <li class="abc">Victor</li>
 <li class="abc">Simon</li>
 <li>Adam</li>
 <li>Peter</li>
 <li class="abc">Tom</li>
</ul>
```

There is 3xli with abc class. Now I need to get order(sequence) number of Simon li.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 33):

With Jquery's **[index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)** method

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this using a selector with [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), like this:

```
$('li:contains(Simon)').index('.abc'); //returns 1, it's 0 based
//Or this...
$('li').filter(':contains(Simon)').index('.abc'); //returns 1
```

Without the selector, you'd get `2`, the index of the `<li>` in the parent overall, regardless of the class.  [You can view a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ddkkz/).  Keep in mind it's a 0 based index, may need to `+ 1` the result for display in some cases, depends what you need it for.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who prefer [You Might Not Need Jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) approach, here is the method:

```
function index(el) {
    if (!el) return -1;
    var i = 0;
    do {
        i++;
    } while (el = el.previousElementSibling);
    return i;
}
```

IE8 and less:

```
function index(el) {
    if (!el) return -1;
    var i = 0;
    do {
        if (el.nodeType === 1) i++;
    } while (el = el.previousSibling)
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a fix for the @Nick Craver answer. I tried using `.index('.class_name')` and that kept on returning -1 for a not found. What I did then was `.index( $('.class_name') )` which gave me the intended result. I guess it requires a dom node object for it's value and not just a selector.